# Mostrar/Esconder Marcadores conforme Zoom no mapa Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, marker

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação android que conterá muitos marcadores no mapa,
e para não ficar muito bagunçado gostaria que se estivesse em zoom out as marcações entrasse em Hide, tentei o seguinte código:

```
@Override
public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
    if (cameraPosition.zoom > 7) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"teste",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        marker.setVisible(true);
    }else{
        marker.setVisible(false);
   }
}
```

Quando o zoom for maior que 7 seria para ele mostrar, mas não funciona.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [Google Maps Android API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/) disponibiliza, entre outras, classes para [gerir grupos de marcadores](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering).
Agrupando os marcadores, você pode colocar um grande número de marcadores em um mapa sem fazer o mapa difícil de ler.

A utilização da *api* é fácil, são 5 os passos a implementar:

1 - Implemente um **ClusterItem** para representar cada um dos marcadores no mapa.

```
public class Marcador implements ClusterItem {
    private final LatLng mPosition;

    public Marcador(double lat, double lng) {
        mPosition = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    }

    @Override
    public LatLng getPosition() {
        return mPosition;
    }
}
```

2 - Use um **ClusterManager** para agrupar e gerir os marcadores(*ClusterItem*).

```
private ClusterManager<MyItem> mClusterManager;
mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<Marcador>(this, getMap());
```

3 - Atribua o **ClusterManager** ao `OnCameraChangeListener()` do mapa.

```
getMap().setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);
```

4 - Se desejar adicionar funcionalidade específica em resposta a um clique no marcador, atribua o **ClusterManager** ao `OnMarkerClickListener()` do mapa.

```
getMap().setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);
```

5 - Adicione cada um dos marcadores(*ClusterItem*) ao **ClusterManager**

```
double lat = 51.5145160;
double lng = -0.1270060;
Marcador marcador = new Marcador(lat, lng);
mClusterManager.addItem(marcador);  

//Adicionar outros marcadores
......
......
```

Feito, o **ClusterManager** irá gerir os marcadores, garantindo que o mapa fique sempre fácil de ler.

Para ter a Api disponível adicione a seguinte dependência ao *Gradle build file* da aplicação:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
}
```

<sub>Font: [Google Maps Android Marker Clustering Utility](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering)</sub>

Comment: não entendi de forma precisa como eu deveria agrupar o ClusterManager pode me ajudar nessa parte?

Comment: Tentarei ajudar mas é necessário que diga, talvez fazendo outra pergunta, qual é a sua dúvida em concreto.

Comment: ok, tenho a classe fragment do mapa, activity principal, Classe ClusterItem, não ficou claro se ClusterManager tbm é uma classe. se pudesse esclarecer um pouco ou citar alguns exemplos ficarei muito   agradecido

Comment: Sim é uma classe(que pertence à api), veja no ponto 2 como ela é instanciada. Veja [aqui](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/setup) o que fazer a poder utilizar.

Answer (score 1):

Existe um método que é funcional, não é indicado mas da certo para desaparecer com todos marcadores ao mesmo tempo conforme o valor do zoom.

Implemente a classe com:

```
public class MapsActivity extends SupportMapFragment implements OnMapReadyCallback GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener {
```

Na criação de seu mapa:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mapa = googleMap;
    mapa.setOnCameraChangeListener(getOnCameraChangeListener());
}
```

Implementos e metodos:

```
public GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener getOnCameraChangeListener()
{
    return  new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener()
    {
    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) {

        if(position.zoom >7)
            marker.setVisible(true);
        else
            marker.setVisible(false);

    }};
}

@Override
public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {

}
```